# Long delay when looping through a TList of big records

Tags: delphi, record, tlist, delphi-10.1-berlin

I use Delphi 10.1 Berlin in Windows 10.

I have two records of different sizes. I wrote code to loop through two `TList<T>` of these records to test elapsed times. Looping through the list of the larger record runs much slower.

Can anyone explain the reason, and provide a solution to make the loop run faster?

```
type
  tTestRecord1 = record
    Field1: array[0..4] of Integer;
    Field2: array[0..4] of Extended;
    Field3: string;
  end;

  tTestRecord2 = record
    Field1: array[0..4999] of Integer;
    Field2: array[0..4999] of Extended;
    Field3: string;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  _List: TList<tTestRecord1>;
  _Record: tTestRecord1;
  _Time: TTime;
  i: Integer;
begin
  _List := TList<tTestRecord1>.Create;

  for i := 0 to 4999 do
  begin
    _List.Add(_Record);
  end;

  _Time := Time;

  for i := 0 to 4999 do
  begin
    if _List[i].Field3 = 'abcde' then
    begin
      Break;
    end;
  end;

  Button1.Caption := FormatDateTime('s.zzz', Time - _Time); // 0.000

  _List.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  _List: TList<tTestRecord2>;
  _Record: tTestRecord2;
  _Time: TTime;
  i: Integer;
begin
  _List := TList<tTestRecord2>.Create;

  for i := 0 to 4999 do
  begin
    _List.Add(_Record);
  end;

  _Time := Time;

  for i := 0 to 4999 do
  begin
    if _List[i].Field3 = 'abcde' then
    begin
      Break;
    end;
  end;

  Button2.Caption := FormatDateTime('s.zzz', Time - _Time); // 0.045

  _List.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Consider using Capacity! It can make sense to pre-allocate the list for the all entries in advance.

Comment: @ZENsan while what you say is true in general, the times being clocked do not include the time spent populating the lists, only the time spent looping through them.

Comment: `TTime` is not a particularly accurate way to time code. Use [`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) instead. But 45ms is not a long time to loop through 5000 items in a list. Maybe there was an unexpected pause midway through the loop, such as a task switch, cache misses, etc. Timing a loop one time is not a very good representation of how fast the loop runs. Run the same loop many times, averaging the times of each loop. That will give you a better picture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, I want to consider the entire code, even the code that populates the list which I do realise you have not timed. Because the second record is larger in size more memory needs to be copied when you make an assignment of that record type. Further when you read from the list the larger record is less cache friendly than the smaller record which impacts performance. This latter effect is likely less significant than the former.

Related to this is that as you add items the list's internal array of records has to be resized. Sometimes the resizing leads to a reallocation that cannot be performed in-place. When that happens a new block of memory is allocated and the previous content is copied to this new block. That copy is clearly ore expensive for the larger record. You can mitigate this by allocating the array once up front if you know it's length. The list `Capacity` is the mechanism to use. Of course, not always will you know the length ahead of time.

Your program does very little beyond memory allocation and memory access. Hence the performance of these memory operations dominates.

Now, your timing is only of the code that reads from the lists. So the memory copy performance difference on population is not part of the benchmarking that you performed. Your timing differences are mainly down to excessive memory copy when reading, as I will explain below.

Consider this code:

```
if _List[i].Field3 = 'abcde' then
```

Because `_List[i]` is a record, a value type, the entire record is copied to an implicit hidden local variable. The code is actually equivalent to:

```
var
  tmp: tTestRecord2;
...
tmp := _List[i]; // copy of entire record
if tmp.Field3 = 'abcde' then
```

There are a few ways to avoid this copy:

1. Change the underlying type to be a reference type. This changes the memory management requirements. And you may have good reason to want to use a value type.
2. Use a container class that can return the address of an item rather than a copy of an item.
3. Switch from `TList<T>` to dynamic array `TArray<T>`. That simple change will allow the compiler to access individual fields directly without copying entire records.
4. Use the `TList<T>.List` to obtain access to the list object's underlying array holding the data. That would have the same effect as the previous item.

Item 4 above is the simplest change you could make to see a large difference. You would replace

```
if _List[i].Field3 = 'abcde' then
```

with

```
if _List.List[i].Field3 = 'abcde' then
```

and that should yield a very significant change in performance.

Consider this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Diagnostics,
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  tTestRecord2 = record
    Field1: array[0..4999] of Integer;
    Field2: array[0..4999] of Extended;
    Field3: string;
  end;

procedure Main;
const
  N = 100000;
var
  i: Integer;
  Stopwatch: TStopwatch;
  List: TList<tTestRecord2>;
  Rec: tTestRecord2;
begin
  List := TList<tTestRecord2>.Create;
  List.Capacity := N;

  for i := 0 to N-1 do
  begin
    List.Add(Rec);
  end;

  Stopwatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  for i := 0 to N-1 do
  begin
    if List[i].Field3 = 'abcde' then
    begin
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  Writeln(Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```

I had to compile it for 64 bit to avoid an out of memory condition. The output on my machine is around 700. Change `List[i].Field3` to `List.List[i].Field3` and the output is in single figures. The timing is rather crude, but I think this demonstrates the point.

---

The issue of the large record not being cache friendly remains. That is more complicated to deal with and would require a detailed analysis of how the real world code operated on its data.

---

As an aside, if you care about performance then you won't use `Extended`. Because it has size 10, not a power of two, memory access is frequently mis-aligned. Use `Double` or `Real` which is an alias to `Double`.

Comment: He calculates time for loop only and question is about slow loop. Besides the fact you didn't answer the question, all considerations are correct :)

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn I've tried to be comprehensive and cover more than asked, and I think that the answer as it stands now does answer the question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan your solution no. 4 is absolutely effective. i have never thought about the temporal copy of list items and list property. always thanks a lot.

Comment: @David: I compiled this in Berlin, Win64 target and during the filling of the array I get an access violation. The call stack says it was caused by TistHelper.InternalAddManaged(???) -> CopyRecord -> _CopyRecord. WTH? Which Delphi did you use?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis XE7. Emba broke generic containers very badly in XE8 with their bizarre attempt to reduce generic bloat. Perhaps problems endure.

Comment: @david: obviously problems endure. What a mess. I only had XE4 and Berlin on my laptop, and in XE4 all was fine.

Comment: I tried with fewer items than 100,000, e.g. 30,000 and all worked well. It looks as `Move()` tried to copy past the memory limit, hence the AV, probably just before I could get an 'Out of memory' error. After all, the record is almost 60k in size.

Comment: @rudy out of memory would be at point of allocation. Does seem odd to me. I don't want to investigate though. I'm sticking with XE7 and likely porting to C++.

Comment: @David: Yes, you are right. I hadn't seen that you set the Capacity of the list. But the error happens in Move(), called with an address like $7FEFFF858A8. I can even find the exact number of items where it happens. One less and it doesn't, but if I add some comments to the code (requiring a little more memory for the IDE), it happens again. So this is address related, somehow. Weird, but not necessarily caused by the TListHelper stuff added in XE8.

Comment: With the same reason looping tList<string> of massive string seems to be slightly faster than doing tStringList.

Comment: The reason for that is that a TStringList also stored a TObject associated with each string. Hence more memory needed and worse cache characteristics.